# How to create a site column type as choice using javascript object model in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

I need to create a site column of type choice. Which will contain "Yes" and "No" as two options and default value as "empty" using javascript object model. Can any one please suggest.Thanks in advance!!!!

Regards,
Rajkishore

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btnCreateSiteColumn").click(function(){
        var model = { 
            'parameters': { 
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldCreationInformation' }, 
                'Title':'My Choice Column', 
                'FieldTypeKind': 6, 
                'Required': true, 
                'Choices': { 
                    '__metadata': { 'type':'Collection(Edm.String)' }, 
                    'results': [ 'Yes', 'No' ] 
                } 
            } 
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://Url.Of.Your.Site.Collection/_api/web/fields/addfield',
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            headers: {
                "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
            },
            success: function(data) {
                alert('Site column created');
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert('Error creating site column');
            }
        });
    }); 
});
</script>
<a id="btnCreateSiteColumn">Create Site Column</a>
```